# C# mp3 ID tags with taglib - album art

Tags: c#, taglib, id3-tag, albumart

Im making my own mp3 tagger, and everything is fine so far. Although im stuck reading the album art tag.

I would like to know how to display the cover in a C#.NET picture box, but everything iv seen about that particular tag is confusing me.

I know i can get tags from files like this

```
txtAlbum.Text = currentFile.Tag.Album;
```

but all i need to do is grab the picture from the file and whack it in a picturebox. Then i would like to know how to write a picture (jpg, png) into the file and overwrite the existing one.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and thank you for your valued time.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this

```
TagLib.File tagFile = TagLib.File.Create(path);
IPicture newArt = new Picture(tmpImg);
tagFile.Tag.Pictures = new IPicture[1] {newArt};
tagFile.Save();
```

**EDIT**

```
var file = TagLib.File.Create(filename);
        if (file.Tag.Pictures.Length >= 1)
        {
            var bin = (byte[])(file.Tag.Pictures[0].Data.Data);
            PreviewPictureBox.Image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(bin)).GetThumbnailImage(100, 100, null, IntPtr.Zero);
        }
```

Comment: Nice one thank you for that. Any idea how to read the album art?

Comment: i wouldn't use thumbnail image, because the image quality gets sometimes lost, but use what you think

Comment: Not working for me. Do I need to use abstraction to get it working on windows 10 (Like I've seen in some website)?

Answer (score 7):

here's my quick and short solution for that problem:

```
var file = TagLib.File.Create(filename);
var bin = (byte[])(file.Tag.Pictures[0].Data.Data);
imageBox.Image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(bin));
```