# Displaying an image from a file in PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2017

Music is added to the `ListBox`. It is necessary that when the user selects music (mp3 and other formats) in the `ListBox` and after clicking on the `Button`, the `PictureBox` should display the cover of the album of this music, if it exists. Many of the compositions have a cover attached to the file itself. How to do to display images in a `PictureBox`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the image from the mp3's tag yourself. take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247216/c-sharp-mp3-id-tags-with-taglib-album-art)