# TagLib - Extract Album Art from MP3 (Powershell)

Tags: powershell

So, I'm using TagLib to make a quick batch editor for all my MP3 files to change their tags all at once. The problem I'm facing is how do I extract the original album art from the file? For now I only know I can change the album art with the following code:

```
$media.tag.pictures = [taglib.picture]::createfrompath("pic.jpg")
```

But how do I get the original one from the source file? Thanks in advance!

Comment: i would NOT use PoSh for this. instead, use a dedicated utility such as MP3Tag. it has a scripting lingo built in, does regex, and has simple pattern replacement. plus, it handles embedded images rather well. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey, thanks for the suggestion. I know and have used MP3Tag before. I'm just trying to learn how to code it myself using TagLib.dll, it is also a dedicated library for dealing with MP3 tags, but thank you, again!

Comment: you are welcome! good luck ... [*grin*]

Comment: powershell lets you use c# classes and code. Which is what you are doing using taglib. you can do it all in powershell but it would be much easier to do it in C# directly. As for what needs to be done, its been answered before here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247216/c-sharp-mp3-id-tags-with-taglib-album-art

Comment: @DiamondDrake, I found the solution! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, in case anyone also wants to achieve this with Powershell! Many thanks to @DiamondDrake for sharing this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247216/c-sharp-mp3-id-tags-with-taglib-album-art) written in C# which taught me what I needed.

So it should be done likes this:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("taglib-sharp.dll")  #Load your taglib-sharp.dll
$media = [TagLib.File]::Create("song.mp3")           #Make a variable from your song file
$albumart = $media.tag.pictures[0].Data.Data         #Where 0 is the first album art
$label.BackgroundImage = $albumart                   #I used it as a background for a label
$label.BackgroundImageLayout = 'Stretch'             #And stretched it to be seen clearly
```